# how can i call element by using this in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i call element by using this in jquery im doing loop each loop have div have 2 buttons play and pasue i want to hide play when i press play and show pause

```
    $("#play").click(function(){
   
    $(this).$("#play").css("display", "none");
    $(this).$("#pause").css("display", "block");
  });

  $("#pause").click(function(){
    $(this).$("#pause").css("display", "none");
    $(this).$("#play").css("display", "block");
    
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>1
    <button class="play">play</button>
    <button class="pause">pause</button>
  </div>
  <div>2
    <button class="play">play</button>
    <button class="pause">pause</button>
  </div>
  <div>3
    <button class="play">play</button>
    <button class="pause">pause</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".play").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.pause').show();
  $(this).parent().find('.play').hide();
});

$(".pause").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.pause').hide();
  $(this).parent().find('.play').show();
});
```

Comment: users can input songs so say i have like 10 song how can i for each song pause and play  it  i have loop on one div each user input a song it must have two buttons working

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your buttons and give each button an eventListener by using addEventListener().
When the button gets pressed you apply your *toggle* functionality to the pressed button by using `$(this)` and the next() prev() function.This solution assumes the play button is always before the stop button.

```js
const elements = [...$('div > button')]

// initially hide the Pause buttons
const pauseButtons = Array.from($('.pause'));

pauseButtons.forEach((y) => {
y.style.visibility = "hidden";
})


elements.forEach((x) => {

  x.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden")
    $(this).next().css("visibility", "visible")
  })
  x.addEventListener('click',function() {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden")
    $(this).prev().css("visibility", "visible")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>DIV1
  <button class="play">Play</button>
  <button class="pause">Pause</button>
</div>
<div>DIV2
  <button class="play">Play</button>
  <button class="pause">Pause</button>
</div>
<div>DIV3
  <button class="play">Play</button>
  <button class="pause">Pause</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is it works for one div but the others its not
how i can put this to specify specific div